# Finding elementary intervals from a list of intervals with label(s)

Tags: python, algorithm

I am looking for an algorithm that can efficiently separate overlapped intervals and sort them.

[Finding elementary intervals in overlapping intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8501423/finding-elementary-intervals-in-overlapping-intervals)

Above question closely resembles mine, but my case has one more condition: each interval has (a) label(s).

In python, I represent each interval with the following class:

```py
from typing import Set


class Interval:
   def __init__(self, a:float, b:float, labels:Set[str]):
      self.a = a
      self.b = b
      self.labels = labels
```

Here, `a` represents the left end of the interval, `b` is the right end, and`labels` is a set of strings which will be united with another when an `Interval` has intersection with another.

For instance, given intervals like followings:

```py
intervalA = Interval(0, 3, {"foo"})
intervalB = Interval(2, 4, {"bar"})
intervals = [intervalA, intervalB]
```

My desired output will look like below:

```py
desiredOutput = [Interval(0, 2, "foo"), Interval(2, 3, {"foo", "bar"}), Interval(3, 4, {"bar"})]
actualOutput = separateIntervals(intervals)
# desiredOutput == actualOutput should be evaluated as `True`
```

Comment: @MBo You are right. The example was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not good in Python, so made example without classes.

We separate all interval endpoints, every is joined with field 1/0 for start/end and label string.

Sort them by enpoint position (1/0 works as secondary key, so interval end goes before another interval start in case of the same position).

Walk through sorted list, creating new intervals with current label set, then updating label set

```
intervals = [(1,6,'a'), (2,4,'b'), (3,5,'c'), (4,8,'d')]

ends = []
for x in intervals:
    ends.append((x[0], 1, x[2]))
    ends.append((x[1], 0, x[2]))

ends.sort()
labelset = set()
labelset.add(ends[0][2])
start = ends[0][0]
outp = []
for e in ends:
    if e[0] > start:
        outp.append((start, e[0], list(labelset)))
    if e[1]:
        labelset.add(e[2])
    else:
        labelset.remove(e[2])
    start = e[0]

print(outp)

>>>[(1, 2, ['a']), (2, 3, ['a', 'b']), (3, 4, ['a', 'c', 'b']), 
        (4, 5, ['d', 'a', 'c']), (5, 6, ['d', 'a']), (6, 8, ['d'])]
```

Comment: This worked well with my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

### Algorithm

The following code describes a stack-based algorithm to process the intervals. This is not recursive or hierarchical making it easier for me to follow mentally. The intervals are processed in pairs and each pair produces an interval to add to the output as well as some intervals to push back onto the stack.

I apologize that my algorithmic description is in `c++` (I am presuming it is at least readable for most developers independent of language). It at least has the side-effect of precise semantics and easy validation. That said, I only tested it with the single example, so you will want to check it closely.

### Sample Code (Updated)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>

struct Interval {
    Interval(int s, int e, const std::string& l)
        : start(s)
        , end(e)
        , label(l) {
    }
    int start, end;
    std::string label;
};

using Intervals = std::vector<Interval>;
using Stack = std::stack<Interval>;

using std::cout, std::endl;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    Intervals vals = {
        { 0, 3, "foo" },
        { 2, 4, "bar" }
    };

    // Sort the intervals by their start value and end value.
    std::sort(vals.begin(), vals.end(), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
        return (a.start < b.start) or (a.start == b.start and a.end < b.end);
        return false;
    });

    // Place the intervals on a stack such that the first is on top.
    Stack stack(vals.rbegin(), vals.rend());


    Intervals results;
    // While there are at least two intervals on the stack, operate on
    // the first two intervals.
    while (stack.size() > 1) {
        auto a = stack.top(); stack.pop();
        auto b = stack.top(); stack.pop();

        // If there is no overalap, output the first interval and
        // return the second interval to the stack.
        if (a.end <= b.start) {
            results.emplace_back(a);
            stack.push(b);
        }
        // Added based on failed test-case from OP.
        // If and b start at the same point, we have to adjust all
        // intervals that start at that point.
        else if (a.start == b.start) {
            auto end = std::min(a.end, b.end);
            std::string label = a.label + "-" + b.label;
            Stack tmp;
            while (stack.size() and stack.top().start == a.start) {
                auto next = stack.top();
                label += "-" + next.label;
                stack.pop();
                tmp.emplace(end, next.end, next.label);
            }
            while (tmp.size()) {
                stack.emplace(tmp.top());
                tmp.pop();
            }
            stack.emplace(end, b.end, b.label);
            results.emplace_back(a.start, end, label);
        }
        // If a and b partially overlap, we have three intervals
        // (a.start, b.start), (b.start, a.end) and (a.end,
        // b.end). Output the first and push the next two back to the
        // stack.
        else if (a.end > b.start and b.end > a.end) {
            results.emplace_back(a.start, b.start, a.label);
            stack.emplace(a.end, b.end, b.label);
            stack.emplace(b.start, a.end, a.label + "-" + b.label);
        }
        // If b is a suffix of a, we have two intervals (a.start,
        // b.start) and (b.start, a.end). Output the first and push
        // the second on the stack.
        else if (a.end > b.start and a.end == b.end) {
            results.emplace_back(a.start, b.start, a.label);
            stack.emplace(b.start, a.end, a.label + "-" + b.label);
        }
        // If b is complete covered by a, we have three intervals
        // (a.start, b.start), (b.start, b.end), and (b.end, a.end).
        else if (a.end > b.start and a.end > b.end) {
            results.emplace_back(a.start, b.start, a.label);
            stack.emplace(b.end, a.end, a.label);
            stack.emplace(b.start, b.end, a.label + "-" + b.label);
        }
    }

    if (stack.size() > 0)
        results.emplace_back(stack.top());

    for (const auto& [a, b, label] : results)
        cout << a << " " << b << " " << label << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Input

```
    Intervals vals = {
        { 0, 3, "foo" },
        { 0, 4, "bar" },
        { 0, 5, "que" }
    };
```

### Output

```
0 3 foo-bar-que
3 4 bar-que
4 5 que
```

Comment: Maybe I have made a mistake while I am translating this to python, but it seems this does not handle the case with 3+ overlaps? (e.g.Intervals vals = {
        { 0, 3, "foo" },
        { 0, 4, "bar" },
        {0, 5, "que"}
    };)

Comment: Indeed, I missed the case of equal interval starts for more than two intervals. That requires the extra work of iterating through all intervals with that start point. I have updated the code  to handle that case and added the example input and output. Let me know if there are any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the maintainer of a Python library called `portion` that aims to ease manipulating intervals. As part of this library, there's an `IntervalDict` class that allows to store data along with intervals. It acts merely as a classical `dict` structure in which keys can be `Interval` instances.

Using this structure, you can easily solve your problem in a few steps.

First, let's encode your data:

```py
>>> import portion as P
>>> A = P.IntervalDict({P.closed(0, 3): 'foo'})
>>> B = P.IntervalDict({P.closed(2, 4): 'bar'})
```

The `IntervalDict` class proposes a `combine` method allowing to "merge" two `IntervalDict`s together while applying a function on the shared keys (i.e., on intervals that overlap):

```py
>>> output = A.combine(B, how=list)
>>> output.as_dict()
{
  [0,2): 'foo', 
  [2,3]: ['foo', 'bar'],
  (3,4]: 'bar'
}
```

Hope it helps.

See https://github.com/AlexandreDecan/portion for the documentation.